# How to delete some item from redux state by some rule

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to delete the item in the array of objects if someone id in the object is the same with id in a payload.

My code:

```
case "MINUS_PRODUCT_FROM_CART": {
      const arr = state.cart.forEach((item, i) => {
        if (item[i].id === payload.id) {
          arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: arr,
      };
    }
```

My payload look :

```
[
{title: "Product 1", price: "128", id: "15"},
{title: "Product 2", price: "9", id: "26"},
{title: "Product 2", price: "9", id: "26"}
]
```

If payload id === 26 I want to delete ONLY ONE object with this id

Thanks!

Comment: Just return the array using a filter. [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: What you provided, doesn't look like your payload, it looks like your cart. You said afterwards `if payload id === 26`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you can write this a lot neater, without declaring any extra variables:

```
return {
  ...state,
  cart: state.cart.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id),
};
```

After looking at your question again, I realized that you only want to remove the first one. We can still use filter here, and simply add a check:

```
let removed = false;

return {
  ...state,
  cart: state.cart.filter(item => {
    if (!removed && item.id !== action.payload.id) {
      removed = true;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = state.cart.filter((item, i) => {
      return item.id !== action.payload.id;
     });
 return {
        ...state,
        cart: arr,
      };
```

Comment: `Array.filter` is definitely the way to go here